# Flutter 2.5 update - const keyword on every static Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, constants

After flutter 2.5 update, every widget that uses static data need to by put in const keyword

How to get ride of that warning to use const
or
how to auto insert const when we create widget in flutter code

[image]

Answer (score 13):

This is because by default we now have the `flutter_lints` rules. It is a good practice to use the `const` keyword. However if you feel like removing it, you can edit your `static_analysis.yaml` file and add the following:

```yaml
linter:
  rules:
    prefer_const_constructors: false
```

**UPDATE 24/11/21**

`dart fix --apply` can now fix `prefer_const_constructors` warnings.

Comment: `dart fix --apply` not working for me.

Comment: I have tested it, and it does work, but it still misses some caes it doesn't fix them all if this is what you are trying to achieve. You can't fully trust an automated fix.