# Android Studio always reports a add const warning how can I close it?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

The warning is Add 'const' modifier, its always there with underlined yellow. How can I close it?

Comment: you could add const, if it recommends it, it's probably because you should, but if you really don't want to, you can suppress the warning by going into analysis_options.YAML and adding `prefer_const_constructors: false` on the rules field

Comment: @h8moss thanks, its suppress to the only const warning right?

Comment: Yes, it will only supress the const rule, it does suppress it,.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter 2.5 update - const keyword on every static Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69309972/flutter-2-5-update-const-keyword-on-every-static-widget)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/**analysis_options.YAML** and adding `prefer_const_constructors: false` on the **rules field**