# The const keyword is used in text and button fullter

Tags: flutter

I found something odd, what happens is that if I work on a project on a windows operating
system my flutter code runs properly but on an linux ubuntu operating system I have to
add 'const' every time I create text, buttons, etc.

I ask for help for my problem!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter 2.5 update - const keyword on every static Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69309972/flutter-2-5-update-const-keyword-on-every-static-widget)

Answer (score 1):

Open *pubspec.yaml* and comment

```
// flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
```

then save. Now open *analysis_options.yaml* and comment

```
//# include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml
```

Hence after this, you don't need to add 'const' every time.